# Nginx node.js express download big files stop at 1.08GB

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, nginx

I have this node.js app proxied by Nginx (on production). A route is something like this:

```
exports.download = function(req, res){

    var id = req.params.id;

    if (id && id == 'latest')
    {
        res.download(config.items.release_directory+'/<1.6GB-file>.zip', function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect(301, '/');
    }

};
```

So, clicking the right route/URL the browser starts to download the big file but then it stops always at 1.08GB (the file is about 1.6GB), truncating it.

I really cannot understand why. Any ideas?

EDIT:
The config.items.release_directory is a static Express directory declared as:

```
app.use('/releases', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'releases')));
```

EDIT2: 
On development with grunt serving directly the app without Nginx it works fine.

SOLVED: read the comments below, problem is proxy_max_temp_file_size variable in Nginx

Comment: another weird behaviour is: if I click the url from a browser it happens that but if I curl/wget the URL I can receive the file completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here **the matter is nginx configuration**, not nodejs code.

**nginx write temp files in disk before sending them to the client**, it's often a good idea to disable this cache if the site is going to serve big static files, with something like:

```
location / {
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
}
```

(no limit)

Comment: This seems like a compelling "fix" but, also opens the door to crashing your NGINX process by consuming all of its available memory, no? @Rémi Becheras

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** discourage setting `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0` as this will have the effect of removing any proxy buffer for all your endpoints.

This means that your application server won't be able to flush response data into an NGINX buffer (from which the downstream client can read whenever it gets sufficient connectivity) and be released/unblocked. Instead your application server will be waiting for the client (no NGINX proxy in the middle) to download the data.

Alternatively, you could instruct your NGINX proxy to *selectively not buffer response data* when streaming your zipfile data to avoid any potential issues with NGINX's buffer tempfile getting full and interrupting streaming downloads (which was my experience).

You can achieve this by doing something like the following in your Node.js endpoint:

```js
res.set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
```

This way the data will be streamed directly from Express to clients but only for the endpoints for which you don't want response data buffered (most likely your streaming endpoint(s)).

Answer (score 0):

In case of uploading a file while proxying with Nginx, you can set "max body size" inside of you server{} block in Nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413
```

If you are getting `HTTP 413`, check your Nginx config and either set it to zero or crank it up, accordingly.

Otherwise, I'd try to increase some timeouts, such as these:

```
send_timeout 600s; # default is 60s; context: http, server, location

proxy_read_timeout 600s; # default is 60s; context: http, server, location
proxy_send_timeout 600s; # default is 60s; context: http, server, location
```

For more proxy options, checkout Nginx Proxy module documentation ([link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)).

Comment: mmm, I think I got it with this parameter set in Nginx by default to exactly 1GB "proxy_max_temp_file_size" http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size
I think increasing it does the trick.

Comment: ah.. though, if you have a `proxy_max_temp_file_size` set to.. say.. 1MB, are you saying that your download will stop at 1MB as well? Nginx documentation seems to suggest it actually. I can see how that might be correct behavior, but I wish documentation provided an example describing potential issue with large file download..

Comment: that did it, but you are right I don't know what could happen with such big temp file size I set now. Probably the best way to do this is serving the download directory without proxying it.

Comment: @anapsix Actually the behavior is a bit more subtle than that. In our case, the default HTTP server socket timeout in nodejs is two minutes. When the proxy temp file fills up, nginx *stops reading from the nodejs server socket* until it has delivered *all* of the cached data to its HTTP client. If that takes longer than the nodejs HTTP server timeout, then the connection nginx<->nodejs gets closed by nodejs, and nginx will simply finish delivering what it has in the cache file and then close the connection to the HTTP client.

Comment: @anapsix So the right way to reason about it is, with both default settings (2min socket timeout in nodejs and 1GB max temp file size in nginx), if 1GB of data cannot be delivered to the HTTP client within two minutes, they will only get that 1GB. *This means that lowering **or** raising the max temp file size in nginx can solve the problem!* Raising it to fit the entire response from nodejs will solve it. Likewise, lowering it to 1MB could solve it as long as nginx can push 1MB to its HTTP client within two minutes! And, of course, disabling the temp file fixes it too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set `proxy_request_buffering off;` This makes sure that data will be not buffered in case of slow client connection. The side effect of this is that, this disables some nginx functionalities like `$request_body`   that I am not using.