# Downloading heavy images(>2GB) from server using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-ec2

I am using the AngularJS and NodeJS for my project. I am storing my images to the AWS-EFS storage which is attached with an AWS-EC2 instance. Everything is working fine till I was downloading small images(less than 1 GB). When I tried to download big images(greater than 1 GB) it is throwing error.

Here is my Back-end code,

```
getTiff: function(req, res)
   {
       res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
       var name = req.param('filename').split('.')[0]
       var id = req.param('id')
       var filePath = '/mys3storage/' + id + '/' + name + 
       '/3_dsm_ortho/2_mosaic/' + name + '_transparent_mosaic_group1.tiff'
       files = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
       res.send(files)
},
```

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
>
> ```
> RangeError: Invalid typed array length
>     at new Uint8Array (native)
>     at createBuffer (buffer.js:23:15)
>     at allocate (buffer.js:98:12)
>     at new Buffer (buffer.js:53:12)
>     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:419:16)
>     at Object.module.exports.getAutocad.res.getContourLines.res.getContourPdf.res.getOrthoM (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\api\controllers\WebController.js:153:20)
>     at wrapper (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3250:19)
>     at routeTargetFnWrapper (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:181:5)
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
>     at pass (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>     at nextRoute (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
>     at alwaysAllow (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\policies\index.js:224:11)
>     at routeTargetFnWrapper (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:181:5)
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
>     at pass (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>     at nextRoute (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
>     at G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:232:18
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>     at pass (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>     at nextRoute (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
>     at G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:232:18
>     at callbacks (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>     at param (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>     at pass (G:\desktop\unifliBackend\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
> ```

I'have also tried with createReadStream() but I can download one file at a time, on second file it would give me network failed error on browser. Please help!

---

```
getTiff: function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    var name = req.param('filename').split('.')[0] 
    var filePath = req.param('id') var filePath = '/mys3storage/' + id + '/' + name + '/3_dsm_ortho/2_mosaic/' + name + '_transparent_mosaic_group1.tiff'
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res)
}
```

This is the stream code I have used. It is working fine when I download one file at a time. if try to download to two files at a time it will stop the second file and shows "network failed" from browser

Here is my browser side code:

```
$scope.downloadOrthoMission = function(idForDownload, missionIdForDownload) {
    window.open(adminurl + 'getTiff/' + idForDownload + '/' + missionIdForDownload + '.tif', '_self')
}
```

Comment: You will definitely want to stream these large files so they don't have to all be read into server memory (which appears to be what your error message is about). Are you sure the browser itself can handle images that large?

Comment: Yes, the  browser can handle this sort of image size when I tried with createReadStream but it was not allowing me to download the second file at the same instance.

Comment: Switch to streaming the large files and make your question about any problems you have with that.

Comment: Well, we can only help you fix the streaming issue if you show us the streaming code you tried and show us exactly what errors occurred.  Can't really help with code we can't see and errors you don't share.

Comment: getTiff: function(req, res)
   {
       res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
       var name = req.param('filename').split('.')[0]
       var id = req.param('id')
       var filePath = '/mys3storage/' + id + '/' + name + 
       '/3_dsm_ortho/2_mosaic/' + name + '_transparent_mosaic_group1.tiff'
       fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res)
} This is the stream code I have used. It is working fine when I download one file at a time. if try to download to two files at a time it will stop the second file and shows "network failed" from browser

Comment: Multiline code is not readable in comments here.  Please use the "edit" link to add it to your question so people can read it more easily and make it part of your question.

Comment: Your stream code looks like the right approach.  When you get the error on the 2nd file are you attempting it while the 1st is still downloading?  Or do you wait for the 1st to finish downloading before you start the 2nd download.  I'd recommend adding error handling to your stream code so you can see if the server is creating any errors you can see.  You need to figure out  whether the server is choking on the 2nd request or whether it's just the browser that has a problem with it.  What is the browser code doing with the download?

Comment: Yes, I need to download multiple files at same time. If I am downloading one file at a time it is working fine. You check my front end code in the question(Edited). Let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is solved! The problem was the Nginx server. I just have increase the proxy cache limit in /location block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just referred this answer,

[Nginx node.js express download big files stop at 1.08GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039916/nginx-node-js-express-download-big-files-stop-at-1-08gb)

It is working absolutely fine for me.